# Any software or application that would find human type word or not

Tags: image-editor, text

One man got the typing job, from image file for example

[image]

to write into notepad text file. He approaches the shortcut method by applying image to text converter, 3rd-party software.

My question is examiner could understand that the person delivered text file is human typed word with normal speed or used any 3rd party software? If possible, so how? Is there any software which caught the cheating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only text file I do not see any possible way to distinguish which way is used to write this text.

If the file offer some meta info (like MS Word) for example there **may** be a way to reveal the process.

Comment: As suggested by Ninov,  if output was in something like MS word  and you could look at the "Undo" correction listing, you could see the corrections that would have been made made by a person typing.  No one could type something that long without making corrections.

Comment: Of course, it would be prudent to check it manually before sending it, to avoid the glaringly obvious machine typos such as *"…who do not as405 yet share…"* in the OP's text. Presumably a page number, as there's *"…principals406…" further down the page. The rest of it seems to be of such bombastic turgidity that no-one with any sense would read it anyway ;))